# Rep Discrepancy

Tags: support, reputation

I'm looking at my profile page and my Arcade account is at 449 rep, 10 more rep than yesterday at 439 rep:

[image]

But when I go to Arcade itself, it says I only have 439 reputation. When going to the reputation tab, the last time I had a rep change was March 25 with a +10, sending my rep to 439 rep:

[image]

So what caused my sudden rep change here? There was no downvotes on answers or removed posts or users.

Comment: [This](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) probably.

Comment: That indeed. Maybe you were upvoted, cache updated, and then someone retracted his upvote?

Comment: Wouldn't that show as an unupvote on my reputation change?

Comment: @PythonMaster: Not if on the same day.

Comment: This happens when a post is deleted. You had an answer with one upvote, and it got deleted today. The per-site reputation is always up to date, however the network reputation synchronization might take a while. Also, since we see "0" for "today" I think it means it all happened today - did you post any answers on gaming today?

Comment: No, not since March... The only deleted answer I have was when I deleted my own answer with a score of -1

Comment: I don't see this discrepancy anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what *probably* happened:

1. Someone thought one of your answers was the best thing ever, and thus upvoted it.
2. The (fairly aggressive) cache that stores your reputation for that list was updated.
3. That someone in the first point actually *tried* your answer, and it killed their character or something, or in general they decided they liked it less. Thus, they retracted their upvote on your answer.

The cache hasn't updated yet, so this list here still thinks you're at 449 reputation on Gaming, while the page on Gaming knows about the retracted upvote (it's much less aggressively cached) and so displays the correct 439 number. Thus the discrepancy you're seeing.

It'll fix itself soon.

Comment: The fact that his reputation page shows "No Net Changes Today" means there was a change of some kind today (upvote or accepted answer) and was undone today